# Sampling Uniformly within the Unit Circle

Tags: python, uniform-distribution

I want to sample a two-dimensional vector **x** from a uniform distribution with ∥**x**∥ ≤ 1. I know I can sample from a uniform distribution as

```
numpy.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, 2)
```

but how can I make sure ∥**x**∥ ≤ 1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be done by randomizing angle and length and convert them into cartesian coordinates:

```
import numpy as np

length = np.sqrt(np.random.uniform(0, 1))
angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2)

x = length * np.cos(angle)
y = length * np.sin(angle)
```

**Edit**: [iguarna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2813181/iguarna) comment about the original answer is correct. In order to draw a point uniformly, the `length` needs to be the square root of the random number drawn.
A reference to it can be found here: [Simulate a uniform distribution on a disc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120527/simulate-a-uniform-distribution-on-a-disc).
To exemplify, this is the result of random results without the square root:
[image: Without square root]
And with the square root:
[image: With square root]

Comment: this is not uniform. the transformation is not linear.

Comment: @iguarna, you're correct. I've edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: How can you extend this to n dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Sampling the angle and length like above doesn't guarantee uniform sampling from the circle. In this case, P(**a**) > P(**b**) if **||a||** > **||b||**. In order to sample uniformly from a circle do the following :

```
length = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2)

x = np.sqrt(length) * np.cos(angle)
y = np.sqrt(length) * np.sin(angle)
```